# How can I make this line shorter with arrays?

Tags: android

```
if (edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("where") & 
    (edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("you")) & 
    (edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("from")))
```

I tried using an array for this by searching a string array with `contains`, but that doesn't work, just syntax error.

How can I make this line shorter by using arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String lcText = edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
if (lcText.contains("where") && lcText.contains("you") && lcText.contains("from")) {
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] array = {"where", "you", "from"};
String value = edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
for (String word : array) {
   if (value.contains(word)) {
      //Do something
   }
}
```

Comment: You might as well inline the array definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = edittext.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

if (value.contains("where") & (value.contains("you") & value.contains("from"))
```